# Android : "Ignoring unknown 'WebView' XML element" message in Error log

Tags: android, webview

first,sorry for my bad English!!
i'm new here and i'm a beginner of android apps developer! and i have a problem:

it's main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id= "@+id/txtv"     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webv" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>  
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/backButton"
            android:text="@string/bText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>   
        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/forwardButton"
            android:text="@string/fText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

but when i debug my app this error will be shown in ErrorLog window:

```
AndroidManifest: Ignoring unknown 'WebView' XML element
```

**edit: problem solved and the above code is modified and correct code!!**

Comment: r u want to load html data on webview or u want to load url on webview?

Comment: @Sumant - there's nothing to related to INTERNET permission, if you think that is missing...

Comment: @Sumat - i want to load a html page in asset folder on webview.

Comment: @Ali.M Please do not modify your code in question next time. Or if you want to add a solution, then add the new code. Not overwrite it. Also your code is not correct right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove this part of the code from WebView `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and add `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` properties to your buttons.

Comment: @ evilone:no need for android.webkit.WebView in xml file WebView tag will appear

Comment: now this error appear: AndroidManifest: Ignoring unknown 'android.webkit.WebView' XML element

Comment: Ali.M Try to add layout_width and layout_height attributes to your buttons.